# Is time.sleep a good way to run a python script every day?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I would like to run a python script every day in my EC2 Linux instance. My idea is to run my python script with `time.sleep()`at the end and detach the screen using `screen` Linux command. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're looking to run a command at a specific time each day take a look at [crontab](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html). By using this you can set a schedule for when the script should run.

If you do have any output for the script then make sure that you pipe it to a log file.

Comment: Thank you. This is what I need

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a cron job to execute your script at a given time. Take a look at a guide [here](https://www.ostechnix.com/a-beginners-guide-to-cron-jobs/).

Comment: Thank you. I will check it!